# Rails 4.1 Force ActionMailer to return other value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

how to i can force to return another value in ActionMailer method. Example:

```
class TestMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  extend MandrillApi

  def index(email, code)
    @code = code
    result = MandrillApi.send({subject: t('test.index.subject'), to: email, template: render_to_string})
    return result
  end
end
```

In this case i use ActionMailer to render template(render_to_string) and pass variables to the view, but i need get result value from MandrillApi module. When i call the method `TestMailer.index("xxxx@gmail.com", "asdf123")` the value return is `#<ActionMailer::Base::NullMail:0x007fe5c433ab10>`

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create separate class (not a descendant of `ActionMailer::Base`) for that task. ActionMailer will rewrite return values from its mailer actions.

You can use [render_anywhere](https://github.com/yappbox/render_anywhere) gem as a solution:

```
require 'render_anywhere'

class MandrilMailer
  extend MandrillApi
  include RenderAnywhere

  # We need that for 't' i18n helper to work
  include ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper

  class RenderingController < RenderAnywhere::RenderingController
    # we can use that for url_helpers to work properly
    def default_url_options
      host = {'production' => 'production.example.org', 'development' => 'development.example.org'}[Rails.env]
      {host: host}
    end
    # alternatively, you can add this line inside you config/environments/*.rb files, setting your own host:
    # Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'example.org'
  end
  def index(email, code)
    # 'render' is a RenderAnywhere call
    MandrilApi.send({subject: t('test.index.subject'), to: email, template: render(template: 'test_mailer/index', locals: {code: code}, layout: false)})
  end
end

MandrilMailer.new.index("user@example.org", "asdf123") # => result of MandrilApi.send
```

Comment: `require 'render_anywhere'` in the first line :)

Comment: How to i can include url helper and translation, Example:
                                                                                                                              
`<% link_to t('test.index.link'), sign_up_url(@code) %>`

??

Comment: I think the best way is add `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'` in environments (`config/environments/*`) :)

Comment: Well, if it works then it works. Does your `sign_up_url` work now?

Comment: yes, thanks!! in addition to use traslations i include `ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper`

Comment: Updated answer with all your points. Now you can safely accept it, and also consider upvoting if you liked the solution :)

Comment: only remove RenderingController, remember that host is included in environments files :)