# Custom Class Devise to send email with Mandrill Api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise, actionmailer, mandrill

I have a custom class to send email with Devise::Mailer

```
class DeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper :application

  def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    email = [{ email: record.email }]
    params = { from: { name: "Email", email: "noreply@email.com" }, subject: t('forgot_password_mail.subject'), to: email, render: { view: 'devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions', locals: { token: token, user: record.first_name }}}
    MandrillApi.new.send(params)
  end
end
```

When try send email i need validate return value, but when try get return value from `reset_password_instructions` return `#<ActionMailer::Base::NullMail:0x007f821da53218>`

I suppose that Devise::Mailer use ActionMailer. How i can force to return other value?

Comment: You can use Mandrill via SMTP with ActionMailer instead. https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582127-Using-Mandrill-s-SMTP-integration-with-Web-Frameworks

Comment: You can't return another value from mailer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861153/rails-4-1-force-actionmailer-to-return-other-value/31861554#31861554

Comment: @EugZol  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861153/rails-4-1-force-actionmailer-to-return-other-value/31861554#31861554) is mine :). In this case i need is rewrite Devise Mailer to send through Mandrill Api

Comment: Yes @max, but i need use Mandrill Api, no SMTP.

Comment: Ah lol :D Well, try to use similar approach. For starters drop  `< Devise::Mailer` part, change `def reset_password_...` to `def self.reset_password_...` and see how it goes.

Comment: @EugZol when it implemented `Devise::Mailer` force to return ActionMailer Object

Comment: That's why I suggested to delete inheritance from `Devise::Mailer`.

Comment: @EugZol To use a custom mail handler, you must create a class that extends Devise::Mailer [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer)

Comment: Try adding `Devise.parent_mailer = Object` to your `config/initializers/devise_mailer.rb`.